Is it true that monomorphisms of local Artinian $\mathbb{R}$-algebras are regular?
A Weil algebra is a finite-dimensional real algebra, in which each element is the uniquely sum of a scalar and a nilpotent (so nilpotents constitute the only maximal ideal of codimension 1). In other words, this is a Local Artin $\mathbb{R}$-algebras with a residue field equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that monomorphisms of Weil algebras are regular?

(in the category of commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, you can limit yourself to the mentioned subcategory; this will not change anything)
In other words, for a monomorphism $f: A \to B$, is the pushout square $B \to B \coprod_A B \leftarrow B$ a pullback?

Small comment: I don't think your characterisation quite works, for example in the dual numbers $\mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$, the element $1+\varepsilon$ is not a scalar, but invertible.

Maybe I am not understanding the last question. The fibered coproduct is the tensor product $B \otimes_A B$. Are you asking whether $B \otimes_A B$ is also $B \times_A B$ (taken in the category of commutative rings)?

Your editted characterization of $A$ is still incorrect. The codimension of the maximal ideal depends on the residue field, which can be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, finite-dimensional algebras are automatically Artinian. BTW, finite-dimensional local with residue field $\mathbb{R}$ are also called Weil algebras (this terminology is perhaps more common in differential geometry). Perhaps you want to fix the residue field to be $\mathbb{R}$?

@M.G. No, I was asking if it is true that $A$ is $B \times_{B \otimes_A B} B$. This is equivalent to the slightly more popular formulation: $A \to B$ is the equalizer $B \rightrightarrows B \coprod_A B$

@M.G.Yes, I do want to fix the residue field as $\mathbb{R}$, thanks. Is everything ok in this case? Yes, my motivation comes precisely from differential geometry and I usually call them Weyl algebras. But nlab told me that this is both an ambiguous term and not used in algebra, as I understand it.

@AchimKrause I forgot to say: I corrected it, thanks for your comment!

@ArshakAivazian: thanks for the clarifications! I will try and think about your question. Yes, Weil algebra is a bit ambigious, but Weyl algebra is probably a worse name for it. Weil algebra is at least quie common in that corner of differential geometry, e.g. as in the book of Kolar, Michor, Slovak as well as various papers related to Weil bundle functors and similar notions.
